# ¿Cómo insertar en mysql un valor que esta referenciado en la misma tabla?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla y una de sus columnas es una foreign key del id de esa misma tabla,
pero a la hora de insertar los datos me da el siguiente error

`` ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`optica_ita`.`cliente`, CONSTRAINT `cliente_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`recomendacion`) REFERENCES `cliente` (`id_cliente`)); ``

La tabla la cree así:

```
CREATE TABLE cliente (
    id_cliente INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre_cliente VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    apellido_cliente VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    mail VARCHAR(75) NULL,
    telefono INT NOT NULL,
    recomendacion INT NOT NULL,
    fecha_registro DATE,
    direccion VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    numero INT NOT NULL,
    puerta INT NULL,
    piso INT NULL,
    ciudad VARCHAR(65),
    codigo_postal INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_cliente),
    FOREIGN KEY (recomendacion)
        REFERENCES cliente (id_cliente)
);
```

¿Tendría que introducir todos los datos menos los de recomendación y luego añadirlos, o hay alguna manera de insertarlos todos a la vez?

Comment: Hola @Otsoa! Podríás explicar que representa la columna recomendación. ¿Estas insertando datos en forma batch o en forma individual desde un sistema? ¿Cuando  insertas el primer cliente que valor tendría la columna recomendación (ya que no existen otros clientes)? ¿Porque estás insertando un cliente que hace referencia a un cliente que todavía no existe?. Puedes editar la pregunta con las respuestas para entender mejor el contexto del problema.

Comment: Rrecomendación es dentro de los clientes quien ha recomendado esa optica a otro cliente. No se si me explico

Comment: Si, pero ¿Por que tiene una restricción NOT NULL? ¿Todos los clientes han sido recomendados? ¿No puedo ser cliente sin haber sido recomendado? ¿Un cliente no puede haber sido recomendado por mas de un cliente (por otros dos clientes por ejemplo)?

Comment: Me di cuenta delnot null, y lo he modificado a null y ya he podido intrtoducirlos. Gracias

Comment: De nada @Otsoa! Si un cliente fue recomendado por otro cliente, entonces este otro cliente ya debería existir en la base de datos, y no deberías tener problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es desactivar temporalmente el chequeo de claves foráneas mientras inserta los datos:

```sql
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- INSERT ...

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

La desventaja es que podrán insertarse valores en la columna `recomendacion` que no existen en la columna `id_cliente`.

Ver [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f9eabb6a1ec46bf4a8095c511a3cfa21).

Otra opción es crear la tabla `cliente` sin la clave foránea, insertar los datos y luego alterar la tabla `cliente` para agregar la clave foránea. Si la clave foránea es creada correctamente garantiza que todos los valares en la columna `recomendacion` existen en la columna `id_cliente`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `cliente`
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (`recomendacion`)
    REFERENCES `cliente` (`id_cliente`);
```

Ver [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6143fb79579fb78ffb8494d949295538).

Comment: Gracias por las aclaraciones, lo probaré

Comment: Gracias por las aclaraciones hechas de todos, al final he podido insertar los cambios